# Jetpack Compose Alignment - missunderstanding the alignBy modifier

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm working throuh the whole documentaion of each modifier.
Now I got some issuse understanding a compose modifier.
It's the .alignBy modifier.
The alignment with a Box and Text is clear. The text gets align by its baseline.
I can see where the baseline of the text is.
The middle of the magenta box has the same position as the baseline of the red text.
If the box is closer to the top of the row, then the Text slides down.

```
@Preview(heightDp = 200, backgroundColor = 0xFFCCCCCC, showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun test1() {
    Row(Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.size(80.dp, 40.dp)
                .alignBy { it.measuredHeight / 2 }
                .background(Color.Magenta)
        )
        Text(
            text = "Text 1",
            fontSize = 40.sp,
            modifier = Modifier.alignByBaseline().background(color = Color.Red)
        )
        Text(
            text = "Text 2",
            modifier = Modifier.alignByBaseline().background(color = Color.Cyan)
        )
    }
}
```

Now I tried it with two boxes in one row and now I don't understand how the alignment takes place. The baseline of a box seems to be in the middle of it. Do I need two times "alignBy{}" ? I can't found good explanation, or a tutorial which explanes my problem. The documentation and the example on Android Developers is in my opinion not much helpfull.

```
@Preview(heightDp = 200, backgroundColor = 0xFFCCCCCC, showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun test2() {
    Row(Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.size(80.dp, 40.dp)
                .alignBy { it.measuredHeight / 1 }
                .background(Color.Magenta)
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.size(80.dp, 20.dp)
                .alignBy { it.measuredHeight / 2 }
                .background(Color.Green)
        )
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the doc:

> Within a `Row`, all components with `alignBy` will align vertically using the specified `HorizontalAlignmentLines` or values obtained from `alignmentLineBlock`, forming a sibling group.

In your 2nd example:

The magenta `Box` is placed at the top of Row since it has `Alignment.Top` align in `Row`. Then the center of the green `Box` (`it.measuredHeight / 2`) is vertically aligned with the end of magenta `Box` (`it.measuredHeight / 1` )

[image]

Using:

```
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.size(80.dp, 40.dp)
            .alignBy { it.measuredHeight / 3 }
            .background(Color.Magenta)
    )
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.size(80.dp, 20.dp)
            .alignBy { it.measuredHeight / 2 }
            .background(Color.Green)
    )
```

Then the 1/3 of the magenta `Box` (`it.measuredHeight / 3`) is vertically aligned with the middle of green `Box` (`it.measuredHeight / 2` )

[image]

Note that `alignBy()` or `alignByBaseline()` **has to be specified** for all children we want to take part in the alignment.

```
Row(Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.size(80.dp, 40.dp)
            .alignBy { it.measuredHeight / 1 }
            .background(Color.Magenta)
    )
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.size(80.dp, 20.dp)
            .alignBy { it.measuredHeight / 2 }
            .background(Color.Green)
    )
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp, 20.dp)
            .background(Color.Blue)
    )
}
```

In this case the Blue `Box` is not in the sibling group and it is aligned on the top of the `Row` since it has `Alignment.Top`.

[image]